# How detect if a string is within a string with NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

Lets say I have a string "Test Super"

How would I detect "Super" and have the function return a YES?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
return (([@"Test Super" rangeOfString:@"Super"]).location != NSNotFound);
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, every single one of those parentheses is unnecessary. It's evidently just a style thing.

Comment: You mean unnecessary on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rangeOfString:` and check if the result's location is equal to `NSNotFound`.

```
[@"Test Super" rangeOfString:@"Super"].location != NSNotFound //YES
[@"Test Super" rangeOfString:@"Supper"].location != NSNotFound //NO
```

Comment: This seems like the exact OPPOSITE of what OP wants.  He wants *not equal* to NSNotFound.

Comment: Oh, I was just giving examples, not solving his precise need. But I will reverse the logic, to remove confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google finds this: http://objcolumnist.com/2009/04/12/does-a-nsstring-contain-a-substring/

NSRange textRange;
    textRange =[string rangeOfString:substring];

```
if(textRange.location != NSNotFound)
{

//Does contain the substring
}
```